# Unable to write a CommonJS module in ScalaJS that gets "imported" in Atom editor as a plugin

Tags: scala, atom-editor, commonjs, scala.js

What should i do if i want to export some ScalaJS methods as CommonJS module? I have the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@ScalaJSDefined
@JSExportTopLevel("default")
object SourceFetch extends js.Object {
  def activate(state: js.Dynamic): Unit = {
    global.console.log("activate")
  }
  def deactivate(): Unit = {
    global.console.log("deactivate")
  }
}
```

And yes, scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule is in the build.sbt.

What i want as output is a commonjs module that looks like this;

```
export default {
  activate(state) {
    console.log("activate");
  }.
  deactivate() {
    console.log("deactivate");
  }
};
```

What i ended up doing is to use the deprecated sbt key "scalaJSOutputWrapper" and append 'module.exports = exports["default"];' at the end of output JS file.

I did try "scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer" but I am only able to get a hold of "module.exports" not "exports" and the value of "module.exports" is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above snippet does indeed correspond to the piece of ECMAScript 2015 code that you wrote. However, that does not export the methods as direct members of the module, but as members of the `default` object. And no, the `default` export is not the same as the module itself (although many people think so).

To export the functions as direct members of the module, you should write:

```
object SourceFetch {
  @JSExportTopLevel("activate")
  def activate(state: js.Dynamic): Unit = {
    global.console.log("activate")
  }
  @JSExportTopLevel("deactivate")
  def deactivate(): Unit = {
    global.console.log("deactivate")
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, works like a charm!  this probably needs to be documented somewhere though.